# Perform a search on google and retrieve results on second page

Tags: c#, search-engine

I am using SharpDevelop platform and I want to do perform a google search for an expression, then generate a list of all web addresses in the first page, another list on the second page, etc. Using some sample code I found, I can retrieve results from the first page. How can I modify the code to get the results on the second page?
Maybe there are better methods than what I found, for example using google API?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace GoogleSearch
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();


            //
            // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
            //
        }

        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string uriString = "http://www.google.com/search";
            string keywordString = "search expression";

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
            nameValueCollection.Add("q", keywordString);

            webClient.QueryString.Add(nameValueCollection);
            textBox1.Text = webClient.DownloadString(uriString);            
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: See if this helps https://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/

Comment: Thanks Sriram - it looks interesting, but I don't know how to use it. There is a small sample code provided, but the developer did not bother with the minor details, which would actually make it work. I suppose I have to include some library or reference.

Comment: At the bottom of the linked page,there is a sample. Please try that.

Comment: I tried that and I get errors about GwebSearchClient not being found. The source code is incomplete, it does not indicate if I have to add a reference or include a dll or whatever.

Comment: Display the result on WebBrowser Control; wcb.DocumentText = wc.DownloadString(strUrl); Then you can navigate the search result just like in normal browser.

Comment: Thank you SG, I tried the WebBrower Control  (using Navigate() function and then reading the source code in DocumentCompleted) and I was able to read the source code of a selected page of results.